# How to remove header and footer while extracting multiple page PDF to Text using PDFminer?

Tags: python, header, footer, text-extraction, pdfminer

I've succesfully extracted text from multiple page PDF's, using PDFminer.six in Python, and converted it into a single string, but I would like to remove the header and footer of each page while extracting the PDF to text.

So far similar questions haven't given me the answer yet. Is there a specific function to remove or extract headers and footers? Removing the first 7 lines and last 7 lines of each page would also do the job I guess.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

```
def pdf_to_text(pdfname):
# PDFMiner boilerplate
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
sio = StringIO()
device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, sio, codec='utf-8', laparams=LAParams(char_margin = 20))
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

# get text from file
fp = open(pdfname, 'rb')
for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
fp.close()
# Get text from StringIO
text = sio.getvalue()

# close objects
device.close()
sio.close()

return text
```